# ActiveMQ not distributing messages between brokers

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a network of brokers on a Complete Graph topology with 3 nodes at different servers: A, B and C. Every broker has a producer attached and, for testing purposes, only one non-broker consumer on broker C. As I'm using the Complete Graph topology every broker also has a broker-consumer for each of the other nodes.

The problem is: A receives a few messages. I expect it to forward those messages to broker C, which has a "real" consumer attached. This is not happening, broker A stores those messages until a "real" consumer connects to it.

What's wrong with my configuration (or understanding)?

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.9.0.

Here's my activemq.xml for broker A. It's the same for B and C, only changing names:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker-A" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic="tokio.>">
                    <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                        <noSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy/>
                    </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                    <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                        <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                    </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="40 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="10 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector name="linkTo-broker-B"
                          uri="static:(tcp://SRVMSG01:61616)"
                          duplex="true"
                />
        <networkConnector name="linkTo-broker-C"
                          uri="static:(tcp://SRVMSG03:61616)"
                          duplex="true"
                />
    </networkConnectors>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
        <transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616" />
    </transportConnectors>

</broker>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `networkTTL` is 1 (see [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)), so when a producer on B publishes a message, if it takes the path to A (which it will do 50% of the time in your configuration because you've got the broker set up to round-robin between consumers, more on that in a second), it's not allowed to be forwarded to C.  You could fix the problem by increasing the value of `networkTTL`, but the better solution is to set `decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority=true` (see documentation at same link as above) to ensure that messages always go as directly as possible to the consumer to which they're destined.

Note, however, that if your consumers move around the mesh, this can strand messages both because the `networkTTL` value won't allow additional forwards and because messages aren't allowed to be resent to a broker through which they've already passed.  You can address those by setting `networkTTL` to a larger value (like 20, to be completely safe) and by applying the `replayWhenNoConsumers=true` policy setting described in the "Stuck Messages" section of that same documentation page.  Neither of those settings is strictly necessary, as long as you're sure your consumers will never move to another broker or you're OK losing a few messages when it does happen.

Comment: This alone didn't work. I also had to specify how would propagation happen through brokers by adding the queues as dynamicallyIncludedDestinations.

Comment: I interpreted "A receives a few messages" to mean that some messages were getting forwarded to A but not all of them were (and that the rest were making it successfully to C), so I didn't even consider that that you might not be forwarding *any* messages.  I'm glad you figured that out to reach a solution.